# FieldSet em JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Bom dia galera, alguem pode me informar como implementar o FieldSet no JavaFX. Não existe esse objeto no Scene Builder.

Comment: Não existe nem no JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

Esse componente não existe no JavaFX nem no principal complemento de UI Controls ([ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/)), por isso não está presente no SceneBuilder. Entretanto, acredito que você pode alcançar uma funcionalidade semelhante utilizando o [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

Esse layout agrupa o conteúdo em linhas e colunas, o que permite que se coloque labels em uma coluna e campos na outra por exemplo. É o que eu utilizo quando quero fazer um formulário (além de ser responsivo).

Você pode encontrar a lista de todos os componentes [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/ui_controls.htm#JFXUI336). Espero que ajude.